# Problems creating an empty constructor, and initializing an array in a class

Tags: javascript, constructor

I have tried moving the array before, after the constructor. I am pretty sure I have the syntax wrong at this point, I have tried researching for quite some time without luck. Any help would be appreciated.

```
class dataService {
  constructor() {
  }

  //I need to be able to initialize this array of objects and create an empty constructor which does nothing

  var data = [ // Error: Construcotr, method, accessor, or property was expected
  name1 = { name: "Mitchell", gender: "male", address: "201 Burns Street East", age: 20, phoneNumber: "905-550-7379" },
  name2 = { name: "Bob", gender: "male", address: "555 Hello Street", age: 25, phoneNumber: "123-456-7891" },
  name3 = { name: "Gillian", gender: "female", address: "457 Baker Street", age: 23, phoneNumber: "555-111-999" }
];

getData(numRecords) {
  numRecords = numRecords || undefined;
  if (numRecords == undefined) {
    return data;
  }
};


}
```

Comment: Sorry, I do not get it; why can't you set `this.data = [ /* your array data */ ]` in the constructor?

Comment: The requirement was to have the constructor do nothing, so I am unsure if I am allowed to create the array there. But at this point, I don't see another way and it works using what you commented, so will see.

Comment: By the way, you cannot have an array like the one you are trying to code. Either you use an array `[{ name: "Mitchell", gender: "male", address: "201 Burns Street East", age: 20, phoneNumber: "905-550-7379" }, { ... }, { ... }]` (without the "name1", "name2", "name3" labels) or you use an object `{ name1: { name: "Mitchell", gender: "male", address: "201 Burns Street East", age: 20, phoneNumber: "905-550-7379" }, name2: { ... }, name3: { ... } }`.

Comment: I assume you are referring to some sort of assignement or exercise; can you share it, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey my friend you have several errors on how you define properties of classes, i recommend to you to check out javascript classes

[mozilla javscript classes documentation and examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Classes)

first you have a mistake on array definition, this is the right way:

```
  this.data = [ 
  { name: "Mitchell", gender: "male", address: "201 Burns Street East", age: 20, phoneNumber: "905-550-7379" },
   { name: "Bob", gender: "male", address: "555 Hello Street", age: 25, phoneNumber: "123-456-7891" },
  { name: "Gillian", gender: "female", address: "457 Baker Street", age: 23, phoneNumber: "555-111-999" }
];
```

Second you can initialize you array on the constructor and assign to the class with the "this" keyword.

I made a working example for you base on your code:

[js online example](https://jsfiddle.net/vp1L5rko/1/)

Peace, mis perros !